# Scintilla Control Saving bookmarks to file

Tags: c#, windows, forms, scintilla

I am trying to save the indicators (bookmarks) for the file being edited in scintilla so that they are reloaded next time you open a file.

This is my code snippet:

```
List<int> bookmarks = new List<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < scintilla1.Lines.Count; i++)
{
    if (!bookmarks.Contains(scintilla1.Markers.FindNextMarker(i).Number))
        bookmarks.Add(scintilla1.Markers.FindNextMarker(i).Number);
}

for (int j=0;j<bookmarks.Count;j++)
    MessageBox.Show(bookmarks[j].ToString());
```

However, it seems that the index is out side its bounds, any help?

Comment: Which array gets out of bounds?

Comment: Also, you should use a HashMap instead of a List. That would be much more effective as you wouldn't have to check for pre-existance of the bookmarks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this:

```
HashMap<int> bookmarks = new HashMap<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < scintilla1.Lines.Count; i++)
{
    bookmarks.Add(scintilla1.Markers.FindNextMarker(i).Number);
}

foreach (var bookmark in bookmarks)
{
    MessageBox.Show(bookmark.ToString());
}
```

Also, it should be noted that `FindNextMarker` will return the next line that has a marker (see implementation [here](https://scintillanet.svn.codeplex.com/svn/Trunk/ScintillaNET/MarkerCollection.cs)). So I think you approach is wrong.  It should probably be more like this:

```
HashMap<int> bookmarks = new HashMap<int>();
int nextBookmark = 0;

while (nextBookmark != UInt32.MaxValue)
{
    nextBookmark = scintilla1.Markers.FindNextMarker(nextBookmark).Line;
    if (nextBookmark != UInt32.MaxValue)
    {
        bookmarks.Add(nextBookmark);
    }
}

foreach (var bookmark in bookmarks)
{
    MessageBox.Show(bookmark.ToString());
}
```

Better yet, you can get ALL the markers using `public List<Marker> GetMarkers(int line)`:

```
foreach (var bookmark in scintilla1.Markers.GetMarkers(0))
{
    MessageBox.Show(bookmark.Line.ToString());
}
```

**To be noted**, there appears to be a maximum of 32 markers per file. See the [markers documentation on the Scintilla site](http://www.scintilla.org/ScintillaDoc.html#Markers).

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with the following code, However, I want to add the bookmarks content to the end of the file, so I can know where to load the bookmarks when I open a new file.
How can I edit scintilla1.Lines[scintilla1.Lines.Count]?

```
List<int> bookmarks = new List<int>();

while(true)
{
    try
    {
        Line next = scintilla1.Markers.FindNextMarker();
        scintilla1.Caret.Position = next.StartPosition;
        scintilla1.Caret.Goto(next.EndPosition);
        scintilla1.Scrolling.ScrollToCaret();
        scintilla1.Focus();
        bookmarks.Add(next.Number);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        break;
    }
}

string Marks="";
for(int i =0;i<bookmarks.Count;i++)
    Marks += bookmarks[i]+ ",";
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using scintinlla 5.x version and implemented bookmark control method as below.

```
/// <summary>
/// change this to whatever margin you want the bookmarks/breakpoints to show in
/// </summary>
private const int BOOKMARK_MARGIN = 2;

protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;
    const int WM_SYSKEYDOWN = 0x104;

    if ((msg.Msg == WM_KEYDOWN) || (msg.Msg == WM_SYSKEYDOWN))
    {
        switch (keyData)
        {
            case Keys.K | Keys.Control:
                ToggledBookmark(scintilla);

                return true;
            case Keys.K | Keys.Alt:
                SetBookmarks(scintilla, 5, 10, 20, 30, 90);

                return true;
            case Keys.K | Keys.Alt | Keys.Shift:
                DeleteBookmarks(scintilla, 10, 20);

                return true;
            case Keys.F2:
                MoveNextBookmark(scintilla);

                return true;
            case Keys.F2 | Keys.Shift:
                MovePreviousBookmark(scintilla);

                return true;
        }
    }

    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}

/// <summary>
/// Toggleds the bookmark.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="scintilla">The scintilla.</param>
/// <param name="position">The position.</param>
public void ToggledBookmark(Scintilla scintilla, int? position = null)
{
    // Do we have a marker for this line?
    const uint mask = (1 << BOOKMARK_MARKER);
    var line = scintilla.Lines[scintilla.LineFromPosition(position ?? scintilla.CurrentPosition)];

    if ((line.MarkerGet() & mask) > 0)
    {
        line.MarkerDelete(BOOKMARK_MARKER); // Remove existing bookmark
    }
    else
    {
        line.MarkerAdd(BOOKMARK_MARKER); // Add bookmark
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Gets the bookmarks.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="scintilla">The scintilla.</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public IEnumerable<Line> GetBookmarks(Scintilla scintilla)
{
    const uint mask = (1 << BOOKMARK_MARKER);

    return scintilla.Lines.Cast<Line>().Where(x => (x.MarkerGet() & mask) > 0);
}

/// <summary>
/// Sets the bookmarks.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="scintilla">The scintilla.</param>
/// <param name="index">The index.</param>
public void SetBookmarks(Scintilla scintilla, params int[] index)
{
    foreach (var line in GetLineWithIndex(scintilla, index))
    {
        line.MarkerAdd(BOOKMARK_MARKER);
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Deletes the bookmarks.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="scintilla">The scintilla.</param>
/// <param name="index">The index.</param>
public void DeleteBookmarks(Scintilla scintilla, params int[] index)
{
    foreach (var line in GetLineWithIndex(scintilla, index))
    {
        line.MarkerDelete(BOOKMARK_MARKER);
    }
}

private IEnumerable<Line> GetLineWithIndex(Scintilla scintilla, int[] index)
{
    return scintilla.Lines.Cast<Line>().Where(x => index.Contains(x.Index) == true);
}

/// <summary>
/// Moves the next bookmark.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="scintilla">The scintilla.</param>
public void MoveNextBookmark(Scintilla scintilla)
{
    var currentPosition = scintilla.CurrentPosition;
    var bookmarkers = GetBookmarks(scintilla);
    var line = bookmarkers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Position > currentPosition);

    if (line == null)
    {
        line = bookmarkers.FirstOrDefault();
    }

    if (line != null)
    {
        scintilla.GotoPosition(line?.Position ?? -1);
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Moves the previous bookmark.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="scintilla">The scintilla.</param>
public void MovePreviousBookmark(Scintilla scintilla)
{
    var currentPosition = scintilla.CurrentPosition;
    var bookmarkers = GetBookmarks(scintilla);
    var line = bookmarkers.LastOrDefault(x => x.Position < currentPosition);

    if (line == null)
    {
        line = bookmarkers.LastOrDefault();
    }

    if (line != null)
    {
        scintilla.GotoPosition(line?.Position ?? -1);
    }
}
```